# How can I extract only email addresses into an excel file from eml file using php

Tags: php, excel, eml

I've tried this PHP code to extract email addresses from eml file. but it show me on browser like this:

```
Array ( [0] => jessy87421@gmail.com
        [1] => gmail.com@gmail.com 
        [8] => tkm.ab234@gmail.com 
       [16] => rjsajal99@gmail.com 
       [23] => mrwsamson@hotmail.com 
       [26] => p7896546@gmail.com 
       [33] => COL401-EAS320FA71AB8D0DB70A86C0BDAACA0@phx.gbl 
       [35] => Mrwsamson@hotmail.com [64] => stancojim@yahoo.com 
       [67] => 284187.29155.bm@omp1028.mail.bf1.yahoo.com [68] => 1452613452.95435.YahooMailMobile@web161005.mail.bf1.yahoo.com 
       [87] => prantomollick9911@gmail.com 
       [94] => quakenbush_87@hotmail.com 
       [97] => k018707707@gmail.com 
      [104] => BLU403-EAS1665B11DD307579691E9A1A96CA0@phx.gbl 
   )`
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
   $emails = array();

   foreach(rglob("*.eml") as $eml){
     $emlContent = file_get_contents($eml);
     preg_match_all('/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})/i', $emlContent, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);


     for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
         $emails[] .= $matches[1][$i];
     }
   }


   $emails = array_unique($emails);
   print_r($emails);


   function rglob($pattern='*', $flags = 0, $path=''){
      $paths=glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK|GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
      $files=glob($path.$pattern, $flags);

      foreach ($paths as $path) {
         $files=array_merge($files,rglob($pattern, $flags, $path));
      }

      return $files;
}

?>
```

Now I want to extract only all the sender email addresses into an excel file. I've searched over the internet but did not got any solution.

Hope someone will help me to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this header information to your function, this will start a download:

```
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=emails.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    foreach($emails as $email){
        echo $email;
    }
```

Comment: yes, it starting download. but I need to insert only the email addresses into the xls file. just need to extract the emails. @kisaragi

Comment: Just echo the values in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing the header inside the eml file?

The header ends when two consecutive line ends occur in a file.

For example:

```
list($header, body) = explode("\n\n", file_get_contents("mail.eml"));
$headers = http_parse_headers ($header);
var_dump(headers);
```

Related: [How do I get just the text content from a multipart email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662295/how-do-i-get-just-the-text-content-from-a-multipart-email)